# Need help with a table relationships and over-all design

Tags: database-design, erd

My design is a Netflix clone which has movies and shows just like Netflix. There is also a table called `transcodes` which will have information on a movie or episode video transcode.

My problem is, I don't know how the I should connect the `transcodes` table to the `movies` and `episodes` table. I thought about having a `movie_id` and `episode_id` foreign key in `transcodes` but then I was struggling with coming up with the query. I think adding a `transcode_id` to the `movies` and `episodes` tables could work, but I feel there is a more efficient way of handling it.

What would be the best way to connect `transcodes` to the `movies` and `episodes` tables?

Maybe my design is bad? If anyone sees any possible improvements, I would appreciate feedback on that as-well.

[image]

**- EDIT -**

I've updated my design to reflect the feedback. The only question I have is, some tables have both `movie_id` and `show_id` which means one of those will always be `NULL`, is that bad design? Or is that acceptable? Also, take a look at the `titles_posters` table. Something seems a little off about how everything is associated, seems like there will be quite a bit of nulls as-well, but maybe that is fine?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question to ask yourself is simple: Can a single Transcode record be associated with more than one Movie or Episode?

If Yes, you need a linking table that links Movies and Transcodes and one that links Episodes and Transcodes to create a Many-To-Many relationship.

If No, you simply add transcode_id and a foreign key to the Movies and Episodes tables.

You need to apply that same logic to some of your other tables/relationships. For example, can a Movie really only be associated with a single user as per the current design? What is that relationship - the user who uploaded it, a user who watched it, a user who recommended it?

A few others:

- Shouldn't poster_id on Episodes actually be on Seasons? A season may have a different poster, but surely not an individual episode?
- Can users have multiple roles? If so, you need a linking table.
- Can Movies or Shows have multiple Genres (Action & Thriller, Drama & Comedy for example)? Again, if so, linking table.

Check out this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) page which covers off some basics on database/ERD design. You need to identify the various entities within your data model (a Movie, for example, is an entity, as is a user) then define the relationship between each entity (Entity A can have only one Entity B associated, and Entity C can have many associated Entity D records etc) and that will help you determine and design your ERD.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. To answer your questions... a transcode will be associated to only one movie or episode. A user can upload as many movies and or episodes he or she desires, but only they can own it. You bring up a good point about the poster - a movie, show, and episode can have a poster. You bring up another good point about roles - it needs to be many-to-many. Lastly, the genres need to have a pivot table as-well, for some reason I only thought they would have multiple genres. I really appreciate the feedback... I'll refactor everything and post it.

Comment: I've added an updated design.

Comment: RE: **titles_posters**, I would separate that table out. Have a *posters* table and a linking table for each of the relationships, e,g, a movie_posters linking table and a show_posters linking table and so on. it may seem a little counter-intuitive but *poster* is an entity all on its own and movie_id is not an attribute of a poster (because it is not a one-to-one) but a relationship.

Comment: RE: **producers** - The link to *transcodes* may be redundant because a transcode is linked to a movie/show already. If there is no possibility a transcode can be linked to a different producer than a show or movie, then I would remove that relationship